# Calculate From To Time Difference - Total Work Time

Tags: jquery, math, logic, jquery-calculation

I need to calculate time difference 24Hrs Time.
some thing seems wrong in the code

```
if ( shiftToMin >= shiftFromMin ){
        shiftTotalMin = shiftToMin - shiftFromMin;
        if( shiftFromHr < shiftToHr ){
            shiftTotalHr = shiftToHr - shiftFromHr;
        }else{
            shiftTotalHr = ( 24 - shiftFromHr ) + shiftToHr;
        }
    }else{
        shiftTotalMin = 60 - ( shiftFromMin - shiftToMin );
        if( shiftFromHr < shiftToHr){
            shiftTotalHr = ShiftToHr - shiftFromHr; 
        }else{
            shiftTotalHr = ( 24 - shiftFromHr ) + shiftToHr;
        }
        shiftTotalHr = shiftTotalHr - 1;
    }
```

Comment: Elaborate! What's the output? What's the expect output? #ThingsWeNeedToKnow

Comment: Time difference like, total working hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out and working

```
// Time Difference Cal
        if ( shiftFromHr <= shiftToHr ){
            shiftTotalHr = shiftToHr - shiftFromHr;
        }else{
            shiftTotalHr = ( 24 - shiftFromHr ) + shiftToHr;
        }

        if ( shiftFromMin <= shiftToMin ){
            shiftTotalMin = shiftToMin - shiftFromMin;
        }else{
            shiftTotalMin = 60 - ( shiftFromMin - shiftToMin );
            shiftTotalHr = shiftTotalHr - 1;
        }
// Total time difference shiftTotalHr : shiftTotalMin
```

Thanks All :)

Answer (score 1):

Show us your `full code` to understand if you want to `calculate` the `time difference` from `two dates` the try this,

```
function time_diff(start, end) {
    sdate = new Date(start);edate = new Date(end);
    var sd = [];var ed = [];
    sd[0] = sdate.getFullYear();
    sd[1] = sdate.getMonth();
    sd[2] = sdate.getDate();
    sd[3] = sdate.getHours();
    sd[4] = sdate.getMinutes();
    ed[0] = edate.getFullYear();
    ed[1] = edate.getMonth();
    ed[2] = edate.getDate();
    ed[3] = edate.getHours();
    ed[4] = edate.getMinutes();
    var startDate = new Date(sd[0], sd[1], sd[2], sd[3], sd[4], 0);
    var endDate = new Date(ed[0], ed[1], ed[2], ed[3], ed[4], 0);
    var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    var hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    diff -= parseInt(hours) * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
    if (hours < 0) {
        return 'error';
    }
    return (hours <= 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes <= 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
}
alert(time_diff('12/11/2013 10:25:00', '12/12/2013 11:25:00'));
alert(time_diff('12/12/2013 10:25:00', '12/12/2013 11:50:00'));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kaRzm/)

Comment: Hey dude, thanks for the care and time , Ur awesome i will need this code some day

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getTime` method of the `date` constructor. It gives the total number of milliseconds passed(since 1970, I think)

```
var shiftStart = new Date(0,0,0,shiftFromHour,shiftFromMin); 
var shiftEnd = new Date(0,0,0,shiftToHour,shiftToMin);    
var msDiff = shiftEnd.getTime()-shiftStart.getTime();
var hours = Math.floor(msDiff/(1000*60*60));
```

`hours` would contain the number of working hours between `shiftStart` and `shiftEnd` (both being `Date` instances)

Comment: forgot to mention , shiftToHr,shiftToMin... are from text box val()